# org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities not available?

Tags: selenium, grails, mutablecapabilities

I don't seem to have org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities available in my version of Selenium. I'm using version 2.53.0.

I'm trying to use Selenium standalone server in a Grails project and the application is crashing on this line:

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
```

I have a feeling this may be the cause. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

### MutableCapabilities

**`MutableCapabilities`** was introduced for the first time with the availability of **`Selenium (Java Client) v3.6.0`**

Here is the snapshot from the **`Selenium (Java Client) v3.6.0`** Release Notes:

> All `Option` classes now extend `MutableCapbilities`
>     `new RemoteWebDriver(new ChromeOptions());`

[image: v3.6.0]

---

With the availability of **`Selenium (Java Client) v3.7.0`** we migrated from using `DesiredCapabilities` to either
  `MutableCapabilities` or (preferably) `ImmutableCapabilities`.

Here is the snapshot from the **`Selenium (Java Client) v3.7.0`** Release Notes:

> Migrated from using `DesiredCapabilities` to either
>     `MutableCapabilities` or (preferably) `ImmutableCapabilities`.

[image: v3.7.0]

---

### **`org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities`**

Here is the JavaDoc link of [**`org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html)

Comment: Facing this issue even with Selenium 4.0.0. till now we've been using 3.7.1. after seeing this issue upgraded to 4.0.0, but still no luck. any other dependencies that we need to look at?